# What is wrong with this java code? Why can't it be used for "Any base to decimal conversion"?

Tags: java, decimal, radix

I am trying to convert the no `n` with base `b` into corresponding value in the decimal no system. This code is giving the wrong output.

For example [1172]base 8 output should be [634] base 10 but it is giving 100 as output.

```
import java.util.*;     
public class Main{
      
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
          int n = scn.nextInt();
          int b = scn.nextInt();
          int d = getValueIndecimal(n, b);
          System.out.println(d);
       }
      
       public static int getValueIndecimal(int n, int b){
          // write your code here
          int k=0;
          int result = 0;
        
          while(n!=0)
          {
              int r = n % 10;
              b = b^k;
              result += r * b;
              k = k+1;
              n = n / 10;
          }
          return result;
       }
      }
```

Comment: While we often write numbers like 2^8 to mean 2 to the power of 8, in java the expression `2^8` is not exponentiation but bitwise exclusive or (and therefore `2^8 == 10`). So the line `b = b^k;` does not give the result that you expect.

Comment: @BoristheSpider many new java programmer may have same doubt who are trying to do Any Base Conversion. please don't downvote, this question may help new programmer.

Comment: Strictly not any base conversion, but any positive base <= 10. I downvoted because it was a poorly asked question, not because of the question. You have now added _an_ example of the incorrect output you are seeing which makes is passable as a question. I have removed by downvote.

Answer (score 3):

`^` isn't an exponent, it's the [xor operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

For an exponent, you can use [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)):

```java
b = (int) Math.pow(b, k);
```

However, note that you don't reset `b` between iterations, so using `pow` like that wouldn't be correct either. If you want to keep `b` between iterations, you just need to continuously multiply it by the same base:

```java
public static int getValueIndecimal (int n, int b) {
    int result = 0;
    int pow = 1;
    
    while(n != 0) {
        int r = n % 10;
        result += r * pow;
        n /= 10;
        pow *= b
    }
    return result;
}
```